# How to create a directory inside a directory with ruby and ARGV

Tags: ruby, methods, directory, argv, mkdir

I have a program that asks with the termial to write the name of the directory that the user wants, like this `$ ruby app.rb mysuperdirectory`

```
def get_ directory_name
  return directory_name = ARGV.first
end

def create_ directory(name)
  Dir.mkdir(name)
end

def perform
  directory_name = get_ directory_name
  create_ directory(directory_name)
end

perform
```

I will automatically want to create a lib directory `Dir.mkdir("lib")` and put it in the directory `mysuperdirectory` .
In this `mysuperdirectory`  that the user has just created with lib inside, I would like to make a `system("git init")`and `system("rspec --init")`

How can I do all this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Dir.chdir` to change directory.

```
def perform
  directory_name = get_ directory_name
  create_ directory(directory_name)
  create_ directory("#{directory_name}/lib")
  Dir.chdir(directory_name) do
    system("git init")
    system("rspec --init")
  end
end
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you :)